# AngularJS component and waiting for sync function

Tags: angularjs, components

I'm having problems with "somehow" waiting gor my funct determineDamage return a result before view is painted, leaving me with empty lists, however function goes through and "eventually" gets the data.. Needless to say its too late..

So im wondering if there is any way to force view to **wait(throttle)**, **update later on**, or whichever other options I may have.

```
angularApplication.component("damage", {
    bindings: {
        results: "=",
    },
    templateUrl: "views/damage-results.html",
    controller: function(Champion) {

        let $ctrl = this;

        const determineDamage = function (options) {
            //return "blabla"; --this would print "blabla" properly
            let champion = new Champion({options:options});
            return champion.fetch().then(() => {
                champion.findName().then((name) => {
                    console.log(name);
                    //name is logged but well, "too late"
                    return name;
            });
        };

        $ctrl.$onInit = function () {
            $ctrl.results = $ctrl.results || [];
            $ctrl.determineDamage = determineDamage;
        };
```

HTML:

```
    <li ng-repeat="champs in $ctrl.results">
        <div class="champion__list">{{$ctrl.determineDamage(champ.id)}}</div>
    </li>
```

Ive "searched whole web" and I cant seem to figure out how to get my result.. also note that if i would to put return "blabla" view would get that info. So to my poor understanding, everything is okay except that my component doesn't wait for funct determineDamage to go through to the end. Any ideas or hints?

Edit: note: its not empty that i get, to be specific i get [object Promise] returned as from my return champion.fetch line.

Answer (score 0):

it's the guy from gitter :D

So what you have here is a function determineDamage that does not return a value but a promise.

This promise has a few methods on it that can be chained

```
then

catch

finally
```

What this means is when you call determineDamage() you will an Promise object with those methods

```
var promise = determineDamage();

determineDamage
.then(function(response){
//Called on succcess
})
.catch(function(error){
//Called on error
})
.finally(function(){
//Always called at the end
})
```

In your case what you want to do is get the successful response, you don't even have to make promise its own variable

```
determineDamage()
.then(function(response){
$ctrl.results = response;
});
```

The function passed to the then function will be called at some time in the future and it will be passed your response as an argument.

This means your single threaded browser can call one hundred of these in a row and then keep on interpreting without blocking the thread, and at some point a success or error callback will be made containing your response.